# Why is !in_array() not working correctly? or is my logic flawed?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

Here is the basic logic of what I'm trying to do that doesn't seem to be working.

1. Loop through an array of the alphabet
2. For each letter, loop through XML and if the program name starts with the current letter, and the major is not already in the array of output, then output a link with some data from the XML
3. Whenever the link is output add the major to the array of output so we don't output doubles

The problem is that even though the major is in the array the line:

```
if (!in_array($program->Program, $majors)) {
```

is always returning true, causing the doubles to be output.

Currently on the page, after every link it output I'm also outputting the entire array to visually confirm that the major exists in the array and when you get towards the bottom of the page for the major WBAN, in the first output you can look at the array above it and see that it doesn't exist in the array so it ouputs however, the very next link output is also WBAN and you can see in the array above it that it does already exist so the if should return false and not output it...

My logic must be flawed somewhere - I've tried moving the array_push all around and can't get it to work right - I need fresh eyes.

Also - correct me if I'm wrong, but the reason I can't just purge the duplicates from the XML is because the full XML nodes aren't duplicates - just the major is.

For example, here is the XML - only the Program and MajorDescription would be duplicated so the full XML node wouldn't be considered a duplicate?:

```
<ProgramList>
    <MajorDescription>WEB ANIMATION AND DESIGN</MajorDescription>
    <Program>WBAN</Program>
    <ProgramLocations>
        <ProgramLocation>
            <Campus>Barrie</Campus>
        </ProgramLocation>
    </ProgramLocations>
    <Term>201310</Term>
</ProgramList>
```

Full code:

```
<?php 
$majors = array();
foreach ($alphabet as $l){
    $upper = strtoupper($l);                            

    foreach ($listxml->ProgramList as $program) {
        $letter = substr($program->MajorDescription, 0, 1);
        if (strcasecmp($letter, $l) == 0) {
            $count1++;
            $noprograms = false;
        }                               
    }

    if ($count1 == 0) {
        echo "<div id='$l' class='letter noprograms'>"; 
    } else {
        echo "<div id='$l' class='letter'>";
    }                           

    echo "<h2>$upper</h2>";

    foreach ($listxml->ProgramList as $program) {                             
        $letter = substr($program->MajorDescription, 0, 1);                

        if (strcasecmp($letter, $l) == 0) { 

            foreach ($majors as $major){
                echo "<p>".$major."</p>";
            }                  
            //this is where the problem is - this is always coming back true even if the major is in the array 
            if (!in_array($program->Program, $majors)) {                                    
                echo "<a href='../program/?major=".$program->Program."' class='programLink'>".$program->Program." - ".strtoupper($program->MajorDescription)."</a> - <a target='_BLANK' href='http://www.ontariocolleges.ca/SearchResults/GEORGIAN/_/N-1z1419r?Ntt=".rawurlencode($program->MajorDescription)."&Ns1=Program_Title_SORT&Ns2=0&Qo=20&SearchWithin=on'>Apply Now</a><br />";                                                                                                           
                array_push($majors, $program->Program);
            }                                                                       
            $count++;                                   
        }                               
    }
    if ($count == 0) {
        echo "<em class='noprograms'>No Programs</em><br />";
    }
    echo "</div>";                      
    $count = 0;
    $count1 = 0;
}

if ($noprograms) {
    echo '<div id="noprograms"><em>No results. Try broadening the search filters.</em></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: From the documentation of [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php): `Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.`

Comment: Also, why is the $count++ on the outside of the if statement?

Comment: In your xml it seems the program element should encapsulate major and program locations.  Your currernt xml has programlist to be a collection of programs, programlocations, and other things.

Comment: For reference, SimpleXML sucks.  For this reason among others.

Comment: @Ray the top level XML is <ArrayOfProgramList> with a <ProgramList> for each program. I can't change the XML.

Comment: @AlexLunix - oops, I forgot to move that inside the if when I added the duplicate check, although that wouldn't affect this - and I can take it out anyway, since I'm now using the class="noprograms" on the parent div and setting to display:none; rather than showing the <em> saying no programs.

Comment: @tsdexter ah, got it programlist is actually a list item in an array.

Comment: @Ray yeah, it's a little awkward that it's named ProgramList when it's not a list, but a list item - unfortunately, IT builds the web service and Web Team (me) just gets to consume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the node to a string value:

```
if (!in_array((string)$program->Program, $majors)) {
```

And:

```
array_push($majors, (string)$program->Program);
```

It's one of those things you have to get used to while using SimpleXML; functions that implicitly cast variables to a string don't need this special treatment, but if you're really paranoid I would suggest casting everything ;-)

For instance, `substr()` doesn't need the cast, because it expects the first argument to be a string anyway and it will cast it automatically.

Comment: shouldn't in array just work with objects, too? probably the strict parameter only needs to be set to true? -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12642736/367456

Comment: Thanks so much! That did it.. Good to know from now on. I come from a asp.net for backend ... PHP is somewhat new to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!in_array($program->Program, $majors, true)) {
                                          ^^^^
```

`in_array` has a strict parameter, you should use it when dealing with objects (as you do).

Another alternative is the [`SplObjectStorage`](http://php.net/SplObjectStorage).

```
$majors = new SplObjectStorage;

$majors->containts($program->Program);

$majors->attach($program->Program);
```

And finally the key variant:

```
$programName = (string) $program->Program;

isset($majors[$programName]);

$majors[$programName] = 1;
```

Comment: The strict didn't seem to work. But the string casting does. Should I use strict and string casting?

Comment: So the question is what is less resource intensive using an array and casting the XML as a string into it, or using the SplObjectStorage?

Comment: if you're casting to string (when using in_array and when adding), you do not need the strict parameter. Probably in_array doesn't work at all with in_array the way we think because the objects change.

Comment: Resources: Depends. Go with strings. If you run into memory issues, try something else. Array + strings is perhaps better, consider to use array keys instead of values, so you don't need to call that many functions. I added a third example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you may have a problem in this part :

```
foreach ($listxml->ProgramList as $program) {                             
    $letter = substr($program->MajorDescription, 0, 1);                

    if (strcasecmp($letter, $l) == 0) { 

        foreach ($majors as $major){
            echo "<p>".$major."</p>";
        }                  
        //this is where the problem is - this is always coming back true even if the major is in the array 
        if (!in_array($program->Program, $majors)) {                                    
            echo "<a href='../program/?major=".$program->Program."' class='programLink'>".$program->Program." - ".strtoupper($program->MajorDescription)."</a> - <a target='_BLANK' href='http://www.ontariocolleges.ca/SearchResults/GEORGIAN/_/N-1z1419r?Ntt=".rawurlencode($program->MajorDescription)."&Ns1=Program_Title_SORT&Ns2=0&Qo=20&SearchWithin=on'>Apply Now</a><br />";                                                                                                           
            array_push($majors, $program->Program);
        }                                                                       
        $count++;                                   
    }                               
}
```

For each element in `$listxml->ProgramList` you'll print all your `$majors`.

You should try to put the

```
        foreach ($majors as $major){
            echo "<p>".$major."</p>";
        }
```

loop after of the `foreach ($listxml->ProgramList as $program) {` loop.

Also you do the same test twice :

```
foreach ($listxml->ProgramList as $program) {                             
    $letter = substr($program->MajorDescription, 0, 1);                

    if (strcasecmp($letter, $l) == 0) {
```

Maybe you can optimize your script a little by putting the both blocks together ?

Comment: The foreach($majors as $major) was supposed to print all majors for each ProgramList - it was only there to see the array after each element to check if it was populating properly. I've entirely removed that whole foreach now that I got it working.. it was just some debug code basically.